# Open Form at certain location in MdiForm

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I was thinking to create my own Menu in Mdiform, something like this:

[image: Main Menu, MdiForm]

End then I would create another Form which would open up when I click on the buttons to the left. However, I would like to open this form as maximized but without hiding menu buttons on the left from my MdiForm. Is this possible and if so, how can this be achieved?

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  If the panel on the left side is docked, your MDI "space" is the remaining area.  MDI is old though, I would reconsider this and just use UserControls instead of Forms and put those in a paneled container.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the input LarsTech...
Meanwhile, I have entered code to solve this:

```
FORM_MANAGE_PRODUCT formProduct = new FORM_MANAGE_PRODUCT();
        formProduct.TopLevel = false;
        formProduct.AutoScroll = true;
        MAIN_PANEL.Controls.Add(formProduct);
        formProduct.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        formProduct.Show();
```